# How to set different styles for hundreds of different URLs in browser extension?

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

I'm studying how to create browser extensions, using [simple example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension) from Mozilla site, which adds a red border to any pages loaded from "mozilla.org" or any of its subdomains. How to set different styles for hundreds of different URLs?

I tried to add new style to the `manifest.json` file and it works (see content_scripts section):

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Borderify",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Adds a solid red border to all webpages matching mozilla.org.",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "borderify@mozilla.org",
      "strict_min_version": "45.0"
    }
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*", "*://*.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["borderify.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.opera.com/*", "*://*.stackoverflow.com/*"],
      "js": ["borderify_green.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

Here files `borderify.js` and `borderify_green.js` contain the styles rules:

```
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
```

and

```
document.body.style.border = "5px solid green";
```

respectively.

But if I need to set different styles for hundreds of URLs? I guess that I cannot use `manifest.json` file for this purpose and need to set these styles in separate file.

How to set these styles for hundreds of URLs in a proper way?

Comment: When you say hundreds of URLs are you talking about setting the style for all URLs, or a specific 100 URLs you have personally selected?

Comment: Yes, I want to specify 100 different URLs and styles for them. For example, for *://*.mozilla.org/* - to set red border, for *://*.google.com/* - green border, for *://*.opera.com/* - blue border and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In your `manifest.json`, look at the `content_scripts` part, especially at those two objects inside it.

The `matches` property of those objects tell your extension on what URLs your code should get executed.

---

**To execute specific code on every page:**

So to execute your code on every site (just as an example), change `"*://*.mozilla.org/*", "*://*.google.com/*"]` to `["*://*"]`.

---

The `*` acts as a "any". To your extension, `*://*.mozilla.org/*` means: "Execute the code on any protocol on any supdomain of mozilla.org on any directory."

`*://*` then means "Execute the code on any protocol on any domain.

**To execute different code on different URLs**:

I'm afraid in this case you need to add every specific case to your manifest by hand:

```
{
   "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
   "js": ["borderify.js"]
},
{
   "matches": ["*://*.opera.com/*"],
   "js": ["borderify_green.js"]
},
{ 
   "matches": ["*://*.somedomain.com/*"],
   "js": ["some_file.js"]
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can execute some code on every page that checks on what page you are on and loads the relevant .js file of that page.

Comment: I want to specify 100 different URLs e.g., and set to each of them its own style. For example, for ://.mozilla.org/* - to set red border, for ://.google.com/* - green border, for ://.opera.com/* - blue border and so on.

Comment: @VitaliyTretyakov Okay, I see. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: OK. But if we need to specify hundreds of URLs and styles for them - is it properly to set these rules in `manifest.json` file? In this case it increases its size and becomes very "heavy"...

Comment: @VitaliyTretyakov Yes, the file gets very bloated then. I think the best approach would be to go as described in the very last senctence of my answer.